# How to communicate with an external SQL database through an Android app?

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I have an Android app which writes/reads from an external SQL database through a PHP script. Both the database and the PHP script is hosted on Amazon Web Services (AWS). The app sends HTTP request to the PHP script, and the PHP script communicates with the database.

Are there easier ways to connect the app with the database? I feel like this method is kinda hacky. Or is this how it is done? Is it possible to avoid the PHP script entirely and just communicate with the database through Java in the app?

Below is the code for fetching everything in the database.

The php script:

```
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        echo "rowname1: " . $row["rowname1"]. " rowname2: " . $row["rowname2"] . "\n";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

The Java code:

```
requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url = "";
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            textDatabase.setText(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            textDatabase.setText(error.toString());
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: in general, communicating with the DB through API (which you called a php script) is good approach, much better than connecting to the DB directly from the Android App. Your API is just somewhat unusual. People usually use some data format like `JSON` to communicate **API** <--> **Android**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct way to do that, via API.

```
Frontend Application (Android, iOS, browser) <-> API <-> Backend
```

You can connect direct to the database, but you should not. To be able to do that, you have to put user and password in your application. Doing this, how do you prevent users to connect on your database and changing all they want? There are many more points against this approach.

Look for `REST APIs`, or maybe `GraphQL`.